# Can Kafka log compaction work based on event time of record

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka log compaction helps maintain latest record of each unique key. Latest record means last arrived record for a given key. But can this definition of latest record be modified so that Kafka checks the record timestamp (event time)?
For example, let's say record (k1, value1) arrives first with record timestamp t5 and Kafka appends it to the tail of the active segment of target topic's partition. After a minute, record with same key (k1, value2) arrives with record timestamp t4. Notice that this late arrived record has a older timestamp t4 than the record which arrived before it with timestamp t5.
According to Kafka doc I have read so far, Kafka will keep the last arrived record when compacting the active segment once it closes the segment and compaction starts.
But my desired behaviour is: Kafka check the event timestamp of duplicate records of same key and keep the one with latest event time.
Is this possible?
If not possible, what is stopping it from adding a feature in future to do that?
I am thinking about doing something like below:
When merging multiple closed sstables,
partitionBy(key) order by (record.timestamp) desc, then pick the first one from each window.
Why is this not doable?

Answer (score 0):

Compaction behavior cannot be overridden to order keys by sequential producer timestamps. The segment timestamps on the server-side files are what are used (sequential file order)

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. But I am looking for more detailed answer on why such a feature could not be added. I have updated my question to reflect what I am looking for.

Comment: I'm saying the feature doesn't currently exist. I'm sure it _could_ be added, but it would require [a KIP process](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Improvement+Proposals) and editing the source code into the actual LogCleaner broker process, get it reviewed and merged. It's not something you can just edit on your own from the Kafka binaries or config files.